# beginner questions about canvas elements with imported images... caching and changing colors

Tags: html, canvas

Couple noob questions about the canvas element in html. First, are images that are imported into a canvas element cached? Across browsers?

And second can I import a black and white png into a canvas element and then change the black color to a different color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the canvas spec saying that images must be cached.

With a canvas, you need an Image HTML element already. The only way it can interact with a canvas is to call .drawImage() on the canvas' context.

There's no caching or saving after that event. The canvas prints the pixels of the image onto itself and then forgets that anything ever happened. No history, no caching.

You can easily **draw** (no importing) a black-and-*transparent* png onto a canvas, and then easily change the black color to a different color.

You would change the canvas context's globalCompositeOperation to be 'source-atop' and then fill the image space with the color of your choice.

You could do the same if it was black-and-white instead of black-and-transparent, but it would take more work.